# I need to update values by subsetting byuser email, and then incrementing dependent on the most recent row. How to make this faster and pythonic?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For a project I'm working on I need to figure out if a user has taken many breaks between questions in an online exam/survey. I have the start time and end time of each question.

- Their first question is in exam_period 1.
- For their next question I increment the period by 1

  - if the start_time is more than 10 minutes after the previous questions endtime
  - or the task takes longer than 15 minutes
- Otherwise the exam_period remains the same

I have written the following function which, for any individual user_email, produce the correct values for the new column exam_period:

```
def user_exam_periods(user,gap_cutoff,length_cutoff,data_df=data_df):
    #get the relevant user df
    user_df = data_df[data_df['rater_email']==user]
    #sort by time
    user_df = user_df.sort_values('start_time')
    #add empty exam_period colum
    user_df['exam_period'] = ''
    #reset index so i can use the index label in my for loop letting me use .loc
    user_df = user_df.reset_index()
    user_df.loc[0,'exam_period'] = 1
    #the logic of incrementing exam_period
    for i in range(1,user_df.shape[0]):
        if user_df.loc[i,'start_time'] > user_df.loc[i-1,'end_time'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=gap_cutoff):
            user_df.loc[i,'exam_period'] = user_df.loc[i-1,'exam_period'] + 1
        elif user_df.loc[i,'start_time'] < user_df.loc[i,'end_time'] - pd.Timedelta(minutes=length_cutoff):
            user_df.loc[i,'exam_period'] = user_df.loc[i-1,'exam_period'] + 1
        else:
            user_df.loc[i,'exam_period'] = user_df.loc[i-1,'exam_period']
    
    #return to original index for later merge
    user_df.set_index('index')
    return user_df[['rater_email','task_id','exam_period']]
```

I then merge the result of this function with my original dataframe (data_df) to get all the data into one dataframe.

However, when I do this across all the users in my dataset this is slow (11 seconds, 2000 users), and my number of users will be much larger in the coming weeks.

Is there a pythonic/pandas way to achieve this which would improve my speed and scalability. I investigated group_by and other pandas native functions but couldn't get them to work/think about the problem in a manner appropriate to applying those functions.

I tried using ChatGPT which gave me the following:

```
def calculate_exam_periods(data_df, gap_cutoff, length_cutoff):
    data_df = data_df.sort_values(['rater_email', 'start_time'])

    # Calculate time differences between rows
    time_diff = data_df.groupby('rater_email')['start_time'].diff()

    # Identify where gaps and long tasks occur
    gaps = time_diff > pd.Timedelta(minutes=gap_cutoff)
    long_tasks = data_df['end_time'] - data_df['start_time'] > pd.Timedelta(minutes=length_cutoff)

    # Increment exam period when gaps or long tasks occur
    data_df['exam_period'] = (gaps | long_tasks).astype(int).groupby(data_df['rater_email']).cumsum() + 1

    return data_df[['rater_email', 'task_id', 'exam_period']]
```

And then similarly merge for all the user_emails. This is slightly quicker (though I haven't checked it thoroughly for accuracy), at 8.5 seconds for 2000 users, but still too long given the amount of user_emails I expect in the coming weeks.

Here is a sample of the data from which the number of exam_periods should be calculated for each task_id and added to a new column:

csv_example =

```
rater_email,locale,task_id,start_time,end_time
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar1,2023-03-13T19:31:05Z,2023-03-13T19:42:15Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar2,2023-03-13T19:42:17Z,2023-03-13T19:47:12Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar3,2023-03-13T19:47:15Z,2023-03-13T20:01:46Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar4,2023-03-13T20:01:48Z,2023-03-13T20:07:37Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar5,2023-03-13T20:07:39Z,2023-03-13T20:20:18Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar6,2023-03-13T20:20:21Z,2023-03-13T20:29:44Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar7,2023-03-13T20:31:01Z,2023-03-13T20:35:32Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar8,2023-03-13T20:35:35Z,2023-03-13T20:41:35Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar9,2023-03-13T20:41:37Z,2023-03-13T20:46:03Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar10,2023-03-13T20:46:05Z,2023-03-13T20:51:32Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar11,2023-03-13T20:53:21Z,2023-03-13T21:01:21Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar12,2023-03-13T21:01:23Z,2023-03-13T21:17:52Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar13,2023-03-13T21:17:54Z,2023-03-13T21:24:18Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar14,2023-03-13T21:25:41Z,2023-03-13T21:31:24Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar15,2023-03-13T21:31:26Z,2023-03-13T21:35:14Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar16,2023-03-13T21:35:17Z,2023-03-13T21:42:14Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar17,2023-03-13T21:42:16Z,2023-03-13T21:48:33Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar18,2023-03-13T21:48:35Z,2023-03-13T21:50:53Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar19,2023-03-13T21:50:55Z,2023-03-13T21:58:18Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar20,2023-03-13T21:58:21Z,2023-03-13T22:05:38Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar21,2023-03-13T22:05:40Z,2023-03-13T22:18:00Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar22,2023-03-13T22:18:02Z,2023-03-13T22:25:27Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar23,2023-03-13T22:25:29Z,2023-03-13T22:32:20Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar24,2023-03-13T22:32:23Z,2023-03-13T22:42:27Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar25,2023-03-13T22:42:29Z,2023-03-13T22:45:47Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar26,2023-03-13T22:45:49Z,2023-03-13T22:49:25Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar27,2023-03-13T22:49:27Z,2023-03-13T22:53:06Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar28,2023-03-13T22:53:08Z,2023-03-13T23:10:07Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar29,2023-03-13T23:11:27Z,2023-03-13T23:17:08Z,
foo@bar.com,en_US,foobar30,2023-03-13T23:17:10Z,2023-03-13T23:23:25Z
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset please so that we could replicate the issue and propose something?

Comment: Added a dataset for one user, who completed 30 tasks